# Why can't owner of folder write to a folder created by a different user

Tags: permissions, group

I have just created a new directory called `sync` in the location `/home/sync`.
I created the directory as user `liam`, I then done a `chown -R rslsync:rslsync /home/sync`. This changed the owner to user `rslsync` no problem. I added myself, `liam`, to the `rslsync` group.

I then created another folder in the directory named `test` so the directory is now `/home/sync/test`. When I try to point my `rslsync` folder location to be `/home/sync/test` it tells me `rslsync` doesn't have write permissions to the folder. I run an `ls -l` and it shows `root` `root`.

How does an owner of the top directory folder `rslsync` not have access to one of its sub folders thats created by another user that is even in the same group as itself? Am I missing something here?

EDIT

```
drwxr-xr-x. 3 rslsync rslsync 18 Aug 26 17:09 /home/sync

drwxr-xr-x. 2 root    root     6 Aug 26 17:09 /home/sync/test
```

When I created the folder `test` I used `sudo` as it wouldn't let me create it otherwise.

Group liam shows as this

```
liam : liam wheel rslsync
```

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388499/give-user-permission-to-folder-in-home-directory

Answer (score 4):

New directories and files created by default inherit the creating process' user and group. The process may explicitly set it to some other group (the process is member of) or should the directory have [setuid/setgid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit set, the owner/group are set to match the directory's.

Default file permissions are determined by process' [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask). Usual umask values (`022` and `027`) do not set files and directories world writable.

Since your directory's owner and group are `root:root` you cannot write to it. Also by your description it seems like you did create the file as *root* (using sudo?) instead of user *liam*.

Also note that file permissions checks in Linux are done for full path starting from current directory. If a directory within the path doesn't have at execute (+x) permission for the process' user/group, access is denied.

Another way to set file permissions is by POSIX Access Control Lists, for which semantics are explained in [`man 5 acl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acl.5.html). ACL support depends on filesystem you are using and might require a mount flag to enable.

Answer (score 1):

1. On Linux ownership and permissions for each file or folder are handled separately from all other folders and files - independently from the parent directories state. When you create a new folder (at any location) then it gets the ownership of the user who created it. That is a good thing and is essential for the Linux security model.
2. When the `ls` command gives you "root:root" then root created the file/folder  (or sombody did `chown root:root`. But apparently user rslsync (or liam) do not (and should not) belong to the group "root". This is why they don't get the permissions that are in the "group" field of the permission flags. Instead they get the permissions that are noted in the "others" field. And the standard permissions for these fields are no permissions at all...

Answer (score 0):

you already answered your question...

ls -l shows **root:root** and you wrote **chown -R rslsync:rslsync**.

This means that at least if your rslsync user is not part from the **root**  group you can't write in that directory.

What I'm not following here is why your user `liam` creates folders as `root:root`, but that is a different problem.

could you please show the output from `groups` from your user?

Comment: Hi Christopher this is the output of the group liam: liam wheel rslsync

Answer (score 0):

That is what it is supposed to do: new files (and directories) are created with uid, and gid of creator.

But the real questions is “what can you do about it?”

- Use an access control list (ACL) with a default group: this will cause this group and permissions, to be inherited by all directories and files, that are added. (see also [What are the different ways to set file permissions etc on gnu/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101263/what-are-the-different-ways-to-set-file-permissions-etc-on-gnu-linux))
- If you can not have ACLs, then ensure that you have a private group as your primary group, and set umask to rwxr-x--- (0027). Then set the sgid bit for the directory. (this is much harder to get right compared to the ACL method.)

Note: don't try to use suid bit, it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution:

Go to .service file

`sudo vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/resilio-sync.service`

Change this lines with your current user name:

User=aurelien.izoulet 
Group=aurelien.izoulet 
Environment="SYNC_USER=aurelien.izoulet" 
Environment="SYNC_GROUP=aurelien.izoulet"

Restart systemctl : 
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Then restart rslsync service and this should works!